# Filter object using dropdowns

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got the following object:

```
$scope.cars =  {
    'bmw' : {
        'm2' : {
            '360': {
              'result': 'bmw-m2-360'
          },
          '380': {
              'result': 'bmw-m2-380'
          },
        },
        'm3' : {
          '560': {
              'result': 'bmw-m3-360'
          },
            '700': {
              'result': 'bmw-m3-380'
            },
        }

      },
    'Audi' : {
        'm2' : {
            '360': {
              'result': 'audi-m2-360'
          },
          '380': {
              'result': 'audi-m2-380'
          },
        },
        'm3' : {
          '360': {
              'result': 'audi-m3-360'
          },
            '380': {
               'result': 'audi-m3-380'
            },
        }

      }
    }
```

Its an object containing other objects and im hoping to use dropdowns for each level in order to end up with a result (which is the 'final' child of all possibilities).

So the first dropdown contains 2 items: `bmw` and `Audi`.

If I select `bmw`, the next dropdown will contain: `m2` and `m3`.

The final choice in this scenario is between `360` and `380`.

Considering that the number of children is always the 2 (3 with the result)
im thinking that i should be able to use a loop to see if the selected value has any children and if that child has any siblings. In that case thay should end up in the next dropdown.

In my current attempt im trying to split each level of the object using different loops but Im lost.

I have made a fiddle and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction:

http://jsfiddle.net/bald1/2bdwpa96/4/

Thanks

Comment: Will you be retrieving your data from a database or it will it be hardcoded?

Comment: Thank you for answering, it will be hardcoded.

Comment: do you control that data source? if so you should map it all to arrays of objects that use consistent property names. Current structure is very difficult to work with

Comment: Also objects have no order and can't be filtered

Comment: I see..But if I manage to map the object to arrays i should be able to use the index as order?

Comment: yes ... can order them any way you want but default would be order they are sent

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your object structure to look like this?

```
$scope.cars = [
  {
    brand: 'bmw',
    models: [
      {
        name: 'm2',
        hps: [
          {
            hp: '360'
          },
          {
            hp: '380'
          },
        ],
      },...
```

If so: http://jsfiddle.net/curial/qyfr9do4/1/